# How to pull custom branch to another branch via gitlab api

Tags: gitlab

I need to pull BRANCH-1 to BRANCH-2 using the GitLab API. I don't see any similar features in the API. [Merge Request](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/merge_requests.html#merge-a-merge-request) only allows you to merge MR with the ability to compare SHA with HEAD. [Rebase](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/merge_requests.html#rebase-a-merge-request) has no parameters for selecting a branch. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Why not using pure git command ?

Comment: @Ôrel Because I need to use the API. The code will be run on the server and executed without the intervention of the developer

Comment: `I need to use the API` Why do you need to use API? Git is also an API.

Comment: @KamilCuk read the second part of sentence

Comment: ? Is the requirement of running the code without human interaction relevant? Use git without intervention of the developer. How is it relevant? Which sentence exactly do you have in mind?

Comment: Are you looking to override BRANCH-2 so it exactly matches BRANCH-1, or are you trying to do a non-interactive merge?

Comment: you can use git without developer, is Branch1 a fast forward of Branch2 ? If not conflict can happen

Comment: @BrokenBinary, @Ôrel I need something like `git pull origin/master` when I'm in BRANCH-2 via API. If conflict - cancel merge

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to overwrite BRANCH-2 so it exactly matches BRANCH-1, then you can do that by deleting BRANCH-2 and then recreating BRANCH-2 from BRANCH-1.

This is obviously a destructive operation, so don't do it if BRANCH-2 has unique changes that you need to keep. With that warning in mind, here's how you do it.

Delete BRANCH-2 with [this API request](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/branches.html#delete-repository-branch):

```
DELETE /projects/:id/repository/branches/:branch
```

where `:id` is the ID or URL-encoded path of the project and `:branch` is the name of BRANCH-2.

Then recreate BRANCH-2 with [this API request](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/branches.html#create-repository-branch):

```
POST /projects/:id/repository/branches?branch=:branch&ref=:ref
```

where `:id` is the ID or URL-encoded path of the project, `:branch` is the name of BRANCH-2, and `:ref` is the name of BRANCH-1.